# DD to a bigger partition

Tags: backup, dd

So I made a backup of `/dev/sda1` (NTFS) using:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c >/media/My\ Book/backup/Root20131215
```

In the meantime I increased the size of `/dev/sda1` to from 53 GB to 85 GB.

Now I want to restore my backup. Is the following method correct?
1. Format `/dev/sda1/`
2. Unzip and `dd`:

```
    gunzip -c Book/backup/Root20131215 | dd of=/dev/sda1 conv=sync,noerror bs=64
```

Or, do I need to `/dev/sd1` to its original size ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You create the partition with the bigger size (done), then restore the backup to the larger partition without any change to either. Then resize the copied file system to the partition size (use `ntfsresize`), that will work.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsresize

PS: You may need to check the partition table and set the same attributes (partition type, possibly boot flag) as on the original disk, for the NTFS partition to be recognised again under Windows.

Comment: So I have to first decrease the size again?
1. Format /dev/sda1/ 
2. Resize back to 53.4 GB
3. Unzip and dd: gunzip -c Book/backup/Root20131215 | dd of=/dev/sda1 conv=sync,noerror bs=64
4. Resize back to 85 GB

Comment: No, you dd it on the new size.

Comment: Yes, you just dd the first few Gbytes onto the larger partition.  Sorry to be unclear!

Comment: PS: I would copy with `dd bs=32M ...` to be a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

When you dd the smaller partition inside into a larger partition in effect you transferred a smaller filesystem into a larger partition that could then accommodate a larger filesystem, thus one needs to resize/enlarge the undersized filesystem/volume in order to fully utilized larger the partition that now hosts the aforementioned filesystem.

Do a sanity check:

```
# ntfsresize --info /dev/sdXY
```

Proceed to expand the volume/filesystem towards the actual partition size span:

```
# ntfsresize /dev/sdXY
```

After it is all said and done, check the ntfs for consistency on windows (naturally, replace `C:` with whichever drive letter is apropos of your configuration):

```
> chkdsk C: /f
```